# List Picker in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

```
private void ListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (listPicker1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;}
```

I am binding list to list picker, my list picker contains data like this:

1
2
3
4

but whenever I select on 4 or other member, in listpicker it shows 4, but within a moment by default it appears 1.
How to overcome from this problem??

Comment: Where is your code ..? are you assigning item source to your list picker on OnNavigatedTo?

Comment: Did you tired to put Break point in the SelectedItem property of the listpicker and check from where the value 1 is coming from in the call stack?

Comment: I get the selected item from list picker but problem is there in designer within an one second by default the first index or first item appears,
I want the selected item in list picker in designer.
see my code.

Comment: @VirajShah Where are you assigning item source of list picker.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal yes,I am assigning items source to my list picer in OnNavigatedTo event. Is there problem?

Comment: I tried with break point, I come to point that rount trip occuring, So every time I select item from list picker, again item source is called. Now how to solve this?

Comment: @Jaihind yes,I am calling items source in OnNavigatedTo event.

Comment: yes.. Every time selection change gets called, OnNavigatedTo automatically gets called, so My answer would be same as what jaihind gave

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal thank you very much for your time and help. Keep it up man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
            {
              YourListPicker.ItemsSource = yourItemSource;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @VirajShah http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/asking-upvote-for-accepted-answer go with links